# Linking fields from multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two data tables, each on different sheets.  Both sheets have Patient IDs, but only one of the sheets have the patient age.

I want to bring the patient age to a column on the sheet which doesn't have the age and I want to use the patient name as an identifier of some kind to make sure the correctage connects to the correct corresponding patient.

I should also mention the sheet with the age only has the patient info on 1 row where as the other sheet has multiple rows for each patient and I need the Age to be in a column for every row.  This will appear to be duplicate data but it is not.

Can I do this in Excel?

Comment: you can do this with VLOOKUP, google how to use this function, its the first thing pretty much anyone learns when starting out with Excel :)

Comment: also, if you provide some sample data, you will be more likely to get an answer on here. Welcome to SU

Answer (score 0):

You could use `VLOOKUP` to do that, all you have to do is use an external reference to the other workbook.

If you are not using Excel tables, lets assume you have your `PatientID` at column `A` and that the table to look for the age goes from `A1` to `F1000`, with `Age` at column `B`.

For row 1, you will need to use something like this in each cell you want the age:

```
 =VLOOKUP($A1, [WorkbookWithAge.xls]Worksheet!$A$1:$F$1000, 2)
```

[Here you have an excellent resource for learning the details of `VLOOKUP`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7gQ-PgYkMc), plus you get to know [my excel crush](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJtUOos_MwJa_Ewii-R3cJA).

`VLOOKUP` has some drawbacks, it does require that your lookup range have the lookup column at the leftmost column, and it breaks easily.

So, consider using `MATCH` to find out the column number of `Age`:

```
 MATCH("Age",[WorkbookWithAge.xls]Worksheet!$A$1:$F$1,0)
```

She also has [a really good video about how to use `INDEX` and `MATCH'`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F264FpBDX28) which could become handy to figure out the column number and have a more robust formula.